# Any differences between @objc and IBAction when programmatically creating UIButton event?

Tags: swift, ibaction, target-action

When creating an eventhandler from a `UIButton` from the Storyboard, Swift adds `@IBAction` before `func`. When adding an event programmatically to a `UIButton` to a `func`, Swift gives a error and says I need to add `@objc` in front of my method, but when I add `@IBAction`, it compiles as well.

Are there an difference between the 2 and which should I use when adding an event to my `UIButton` *programmatically*?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `IBAction` prefix already exposes the method to the Objective-C runtime, so there is no need to prefix it additionally with `@objc`.

Since IB stands for **Interface Builder**, it's unnecessary to use it when you create a button programmatically. All it does (besides exposing the method to Objective-C) is make Interface Builder list the function as an action in the Connections inspector.